# Information about info pages!

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

Have  the  info pages been introduced recently? (or have I failed to see them so far?).

Comment: Which pages exactly?

Comment: This one, for instance https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info, or this one https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/word-choice/info. And this https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/grammar/info

Answer (score 9):

Actually, this feature was introduced in 2010:

> 2010-07-22: "Info" tab of tags, including a [tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/create-a-tag-homepage-faq/49723#49723) and a [tag synonym proposal system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57479) implemented.
>   <sub>[Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99024/323179)</sub>

So it predates the site by two weeks. This site—and its [Community user](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community)—were created on 2010-08-05.

Visibility has also been noted as a problem before, on other sites at least. (Nothing has been changed however.) Here are some examples:

- Meta Stack Overflow: [Should tag wikis get more exposure?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323800/6083675)
- Main Meta: [Highlighting the Tag Wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179500/323179)
- Main Meta (after the tag popup revamp): [Accessing extended tag info is almost impossible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/314150/323179)

Comment: Ok Thanks, so probably I am not  the only user who has not seen those pages before.

Comment: @Josh I stumbled across these a while ago, but then couldn't remember *where* for a few months; when I stumbled across them again, I made a note that they were connected to tags, but *still* had to do a lot of digging to find them again the next time I wanted to look at one. They really are very well concealed. The whole "pop-up on hover" thing is virtually useless when accessing the site from a mobile device, too, which I suspect a lot of users do nowadays, at least on the non-developer-specific sites. All of which is a shame, because they really can be very useful.

Comment: @1006a - I found them by chance; the easiest way, I think, is to click on a tag, "single-word-request", for instance, https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests and then click the  "info" tag which is the first one the left. Hope it is clear.

Comment: Thanks, @Josh, it's clear (though it looks like "info" now says "learn more..."?). I did eventually figure out how to get to them reliably—it just took a few repetitions before I could remember the right steps! Might be worth its own step-by-step answer, for anyone else who's wondering.

Answer (score 5):

No, they are as old as the hills. Looking at the history of the single-word-request info page, for example, there is

[image: Tag info history]

That one is over six years old. It's now at revision 17.

These are the pages shown clicking the "Info" link in the tag pop-up, although not every tag has had one written yet:

[image: Tag pop-up]

Perhaps that "info" link needs to be re-worded. I don't know why it's not "more info".

Comment: Ok thanks. Strange I have never come across any of them before, maybe they are not as "visible" as they should be.