# Closed as dupe points to closed as too broad

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

Closed as dupe points to closed as too broad.  How is that helpful to anyone?

My knee-jerk reaction is to vote to reopen the more recent one.  Any better ideas?

Example: [Not a jack of all trades! i stg mark my question as a duplicate](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/439523/112436)

Comment: In this case, it seems relevant both questions were asked by the same person. I assume closing the more recent one as a dupe of the older one is meant to send the message to the OP that making a new post is not the correct way to deal with getting a question closed: the original post should be edited.

Comment: @sumelic - Oh gee, I should have noticed that.  I misread the dates, too.

Comment: On the main site, [only moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933/323179) can close a question as a duplicate of an unanswered question, unless both questions were asked by the same person. So there's already a safeguard in place to try to prevent duplicates from being unhelpful.

Comment: @Laurel - Wow, I'm very impressed with your knowledge of the fine points of the software.

Comment: To make matters worse, if you can't see deleted questions, you get a 404 following the "duplicate" link.

Answer (score 3):

The second question was closed as a duplicate of another question. This is correct: it was a duplicate. That the original question is off-topic is actually immaterial; all it means is that the second version is off-topic too.

> Im looking for a word used to describe a worker who can do multiple types of tasks not necessairly (ik i spelt that wrong) at the same time but a person who can for example if working in a grocery store can do cash, stock, etc. a person who can work in any position in a company
>
> some examples: flexible, versatile, adversed, adaptable
>
> but I'm looking for a specific word i believe starts with a 'd' not sure

> im looking for a word that describes someone who can work any position in a company not a jack of all trades I'm looking for an adjective to describe someone who can work anywhere an employer might ask in a specific field
>
> something like a diverse worker, a flexible worker
>
> please help
>
> thanks

In my view the first question is the better of the two. Both were correctly tagged by the OP as [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) but he didn't follow any of the advice in the tag info (even the short version provided in the pop-up).

[Sumelic](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11333/closed-as-dupe-points-to-closed-as-too-broad#comment47899_11333) is right that repeat questions by the same OP are generally linked together, usually by closing the second as a duplicate of the first. It is an indication that it's the original question which needs to be dealt with. There might be exceptions, where the second version is markedly better than the first — but in that case it's unlikely to be a duplicate question.

In this case, since we have a custom close reason for [single-word-requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/single-word-requests) questions, it might have been better to use that. However, the question would still have ended up closed.

Rather than vote to reopen the more recent one, concentrate on the **better question** (which might be the earlier version, as in this case). But it needs to be made on-topic, following the tag guidance at least. Once the question is of a standard which is not eminently closable, vote to reopen.

Comment: "He didn't follow any of the advice in the tag info"—The vast majority of new users have no idea such a thing exists. Some users don't figure it out until they have many, many [thousands of rep](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10535/191178) because the feature is just not easily discoverable.

Comment: @Laurel The single-word-request tag is not very obvious, but here **the OP actually found it,** which means he must have seen the brief guidance at least. And ignored it.

Comment: @Laurel  while it is reasonable that people might not find the tag initially I also think it is reasonable to expect the person asking the question to be monitoring the SE site actively after asking the question and be able to quickly respond to comments that ask for more information or ask them to read the tag info and enhance their question accordingly.  That people ask a question then don't come back to check replies for days, or find it too much of a nuisance to improve their question seems a bit anti social to me ... especially while asking for a ~favor~ of free advice or help.

Comment: This is absurd. I've just looked at the older question expecting to see at least Jack of all trades, instead, there's nothing. Closing a new question as a duplicate of a closed question which has NO ANSWERS. How does that help anyone? How does that help a future visitor? I think there should be a veto on unanswered closed questions being used to close future questions. It makes no sense.

Comment: @MariLou This was a repeat question from the same asker. Those **always** get closed.

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the fact that the OP in both questions is the same one.

Comment: But we, as a community, did a very poor job of assisting a motivated newcomer. The matter should have been handled more intelligently.

Comment: As it stands now, the question has been marked a duplicate of another question, **which is now deleted**. So anyone who doesn’t have enough rep to see deleted questions will just see a duplicate notice and then get an error when clicking on it. Even if both questions are by the same asker, that doesn’t seem ideal.